# AVI Video Playback Problem

Tags: video

I am using a Raspberry Pi 3 and a USB web cam to record video. I wrote a script that launches the camera and tells it how long to run for before closing. I wanted to be able to stop the recording earlier if I wanted so I hooked up a button to a GPIO pin and I am able to stop the recording early no problem. The next step is to transfer the .avi files from the Raspberry Pi to a Windows 7 laptop. I am doing this through a USB stick. I can successfully watch videos that recorded for the entire recording time uninterrupted but I am unable to render any video I stopped early. I can play both methods of recording back on the Raspberry Pi using omxplayer so I know the video files aren't empty. Does anyone have any idea on why the videos I stopped early would work on the Raspberry Pi but not a Windows 7 laptop?

Thanks

EDIT: Here is how I launch and kill the recording script.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import signal
import time
import os
import subprocess
from subprocess import call
import sys
from sys import exit

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)

GPIO.setup(12, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(16, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

set = 0
while True:
    if GPIO.input(12) == False and set == 0:
        print('Starting Video Recording')
        p=subprocess.Popen("./video", shell=False, preexec_fn=os.setsid)
        time.sleep(1)
        set = 1
    if GPIO.input(16) == False and set == 1:
        print('Stopping Video Recording')
        os.killpg(os.getpgid(p.pid), signal.SIGTERM)
        time.sleep(2)
        set = 0
    if GPIO.input(18) == False and set == 0:
        print('Exit Video Recording') 
        time.sleep(1)
        break
GPIO.cleanup()
```

EDIT 2:

```
#include "uEye.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "iostream"
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/videoio.hpp"
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

HIDS hCam = 1;
SENSORINFO sensor_info;
CAMINFO camera_info;
int nRet;
int Mode;
char strCamFileName[256];
int img_width=640;
int img_height=480;

int main ()
{
//initialize camera
nRet = is_InitCamera(&hCam, NULL);
cout << "Status Init: " << nRet << endl;

//get sensor info
//nRet = is_GetSensorInfo(hCam, &sensor_info);
//cout << "Sensor Color Mode: " << sensor_info.nColorMode << endl;
//cout << "Camera Model: " << sensor_info.strSensorName << endl;

//get camera info
//nRet = is_GetCameraInfo(hCam, &camera_info);
//cout << "Camera ID: " << camera_info.ID << endl;
//cout << "Camera SerNum: " << camera_info.SerNo << endl;
//cout << "Camera Version: " << camera_info.Version << endl;
//cout << "Camera Type: " << camera_info.Type << endl;

//color mode
Mode = IS_CM_RGB8_PACKED;
nRet = is_SetColorMode(hCam, Mode);
cout << "Color Mode: " << nRet << endl;

UINT formatID = 13;
nRet = is_ImageFormat(hCam, IMGFRMT_CMD_SET_FORMAT, &formatID, 4);
cout << "Status Image Format: " << nRet << endl;

char* pMem = NULL;
int memID = 0;
nRet = is_AllocImageMem(hCam, img_width, img_height, 24, &pMem, &memID);
nRet = is_SetImageMem(hCam, pMem, memID);

//set display mode
Mode = IS_SET_DM_DIB;
nRet = is_SetDisplayMode(hCam, Mode);

//zoom
double dZoomValue = 0;
nRet = is_Zoom(hCam, ZOOM_CMD_DIGITAL_SET_VALUE, (void*)&dZoomValue, sizeof(dZoomValue));
cout << "Zoom: " << dZoomValue << endl;

VideoWriter video("out.avi", CV_FOURCC('X','V','I','D'), 10, Size(img_width, img_height),true);

for(int ii=0; ii<600; ii++)
{
   if(is_FreezeVideo(hCam, IS_WAIT) == IS_SUCCESS){
        void *pMemVoid; //pointer to where the image is stored
        is_GetImageMem (hCam, &pMemVoid);
        Mat img=Mat(Size(img_width,img_height), CV_8UC3, pMemVoid);
    video.write(img);
    namedWindow( "Live Video", WINDOW_NORMAL);
    resizeWindow("Live Video", 320,240);
    imshow("Live Video", img);
    waitKey(1);

   }
}
//exit camera
is_ExitCamera(hCam);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: How exactly do you stop the recording? If you do something like `killall raspivid`, you may be producing incomplete files, which Windows Media Player may refuse to play. Try using a different player like VLC or MPC.

Comment: I edited my post to include how I launch and terminate the script

Comment: I can see how you're launching *something* - what program are you using to actually record the video, and what parameters are you using when you run it? This sounds very similar to a problem I ran up against a few years ago where I tried to do the same thing with VLC and killed the process before it wrote MOOV atoms into my video files, rendering the files unplayable. I had a fix at the time which I'm trying to track down - I *think* there's a workaround for knackered files (or you could just close your recorder properly!).

Comment: What is this mysterious `"./video"` command?

Comment: Video is the executable that I made when compiling my camera recording program. @goobering how do i close my recorder properly?

Comment: I'm no OpenCV expert, but I'm a little bemused as to why you'd use a C++ program to run the show when you could just keep the whole thing in a [single Python script](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html). I *think* the way you've built your application you're going to have to listen for button presses in your C++ code and dispose of your recorder there (which should close the background FFMPEG process properly). Either that or figure out how to pass a message from your Python to your C++ to trigger the stop command.

Comment: Thank you for the help. The OpenCV camera launching function would not recognize my camera no matter how simply I wrote the code. What I've had to do to even make the camera open is to frankenstein the manufacturer's software with the video writing part of OpenCV. This has been the only way for me to launch the camera and get it to record video. I will have to do some research into how gpio buttons in C++ work. Thanks again!

Comment: Given the relative ease of working in one language versus interfacing between two, it may be worth taking 5 minutes to write up an exploratory question on why your camera doesn't work in OpenCV/Python. I think it might save you some headaches down the line if you can get shot of some complexity.

Comment: Ok I will open up another thread and see if anyone else has any experience with this. It is an odd camera to use for a project like this so I doubt it but I do agree that it is worth a shot

Comment: ive done some searching and it looks like OpenCV looks for cameras in /dev/video* but the IDS UEye cameras use /dev/ueye instead so OpenCV will never find my camera. I think i just need to import one C++ function (is_ExitCamera()) in order to properly close the camera. Is there a way to call just that one function from my python script?